# How can I proceed trying to solve a too difficult problem?

Tags: discussion, support

I was asking about an [ODE problem](http://www.csc.kth.se/utbildning/kth/kurser/DN1232/berva13/Lab3BuppgJO.pdf#page=16) getting some answers that were somewhat useful. I failed to understand it though and I still haven't solved it. In which ways can I proceed if I still want to solve the problem? The answers were not thorough and monstly pointing to manuals. I would like some more specofic guidance for my specific problem. What can I do with it? Should I just read more manpages? It's homework for BSc.

[How to proceed solving this problem?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/467164/how-to-proceed-solving-this-problem?rq=1)

https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/8495/are-these-coefficients-correctly-calculated

Comment: Related: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3478/23353

Comment: Get some reputation and make a bounty.

Comment: As you say that it's homework, I would think the best specific guidance would be available from the person who set the assignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First do something about the "I failed to understand it" How can you even try to solve it when you failed to understand the problem?

For instance when you get the result A as (provisional) solution, does this answer even makes sense?

If you don't understand the problem, you open yourself to all kind of dangers, don't go this way.

So first DO EVERYTHING TO UNDERSTAND THE PROBLEM

Split it up in smaller understandable problems till you understand it and can make (semi) causal relations between them. you don't need to prove envery link but you must understand them. (And you are the judge of that)

Second  No don't even try to solve it before you understand the problem.

Good luck

Sorry this is a bit of a rant but understanding the problem is really necessary